# spring-ws SOAP — Missing Messages and Binding

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I want to implement my own SOAP webservcie using spring-ws. I have written a xsd, from which a Java class is generated.

This is my webservice configuration:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}

@Bean(name = "foo")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11DefinitionFoo(){
    DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    defaultWsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("FooPort");
    defaultWsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    defaultWsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("foo");
    defaultWsdl11Definition.setSchema(fooSchema());
    return defaultWsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean
public XsdSchema fooSchema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("foo.xsd"));
}
```

This is my xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="foo" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:complexType name="Foobject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is my endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class Fooendpoint {

private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "foo";

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "bar")
@ResponsePayload
public Foobject getCountry(@RequestPayload Foobject request) {
    return new Foobject("string", 0);
}}
```

And finally this is the autogenerated WSDL the webservice publishes at `http://localhost:8080/ws/foo.wsdl`

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="foo" xmlns:sch="foo" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="foo" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="foo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:complexType name="Foobject">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:portType name="FooPort"/>
<wsdl:binding name="FooPortSoap11" type="tns:FooPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="FooPortService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:FooPortSoap11" name="FooPortSoap11">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

in the WSDL there is no messages and operations. What am I missing?

**Update:**
I modified the XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="foo" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:tns="foo">

<xs:element name="fooRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo" type="tns:Foobject"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="fooResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="Foobject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="int" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The WSDL now has messages and bindings:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="foo" xmlns:sch="foo" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="foo" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="foo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="fooRequest">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="foo" type="tns:Foobject"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="fooResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:complexType name="Foobject">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="int" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="fooResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:fooResponse" name="fooResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="fooRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:fooRequest" name="fooRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="FooPort">
    <wsdl:operation name="foo">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:fooRequest" name="fooRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:fooResponse" name="fooResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="FooPortSoap11" type="tns:FooPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="foo">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="fooRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="fooResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="FooPortService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:FooPortSoap11" name="FooPortSoap11">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

But when I send a request via SoapUI, the Endpoint is not found:

```
No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {foo}fooRequest]
```

Comment: SOAP in 2018? Even its promoter, Microsoft, has moved away from it. Why not REST? It is way simpler.

Comment: It's been awhile since I did anything with SOAP, but you have no methods in your XSD, like `<xs:element name="getData"><xs:complexType...`

Comment: @CrazySabbath I added a request and response to the WSDL and updated the question. SoapUI can create a sample request now, but the endpoint ist not found.

Comment: Any solutions here? It's 2022 i know. But the world is not as we want it to be. So I have to implement a SOAP-Service. But parameter binding still sucks.

Comment: @CarstenSpräner I actually looked through my old repos, but couldn't find the solution. Sorry. But it might have had something to do with the Endpoint-URL I was using. But I'm not sure on this...

Comment: @joschal I finally "hacked" around. The parameters and return values have to be of the type "org.w3c.Element". Otherwise, the parameter match will not succeed. So I changed the types to Element and the EndPoint-Method is invoked. In the method, you need to unmarshal the parameters and marshal the result by hand. Not very handy but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody may in need of a "solution" here is a little (real) hack around the problem. The problem is inside the parameter match algorithm in spring. It checks with "parameter instanceof org.w3c.Element". If not you do not have a match and the method is not called.

**Btw: If anybody has a better solution please let me know! It must be somewhere.**

So in case, you got a:

```
// No adapter for endpoint [public <CorrectType> <CorrectMethod>(<CorrectArgumentType>)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
```

You may change the method to:

```java
public org.w3c.Element correctMethod(org.w3c.Element parameter) {...
```

Now the method gets called and you can unmarshal the parameter and marshal the result with a JAXBContext.

For marshaling you can use a method like this:

```java
    private <T> T unmarshalParameter(Element element, Class<? extends T> targetClass) {
        JAXBContext context = null;
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(targetClass);
            return context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(element, targetClass).getValue();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Marshaling of the result can be done like:

```java
    private <T> Element marshal(T response, String elementName) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        try {
            Document document =
                    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(response.getClass());
            DOMResult res = new DOMResult(document);
            JAXBElement<?> jaxbElement =
                    new JAXBElement<>( new QName(NAMESPACE_URI,elementName),
                            (Class<T>)response.getClass(),
                            response);
            jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxbElement,res);
            Element e = (Element)document.getDocumentElement();
            return e;
        } catch (JAXBException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```